# python/jinja2 issue rendering template containing unicode characters

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following code which uses the jina2 engine to render some html.

```
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader, autoescape=True,trim_blocks=True)
template = env.get_template("template.html")
...
data = {
    'title' : 'test'
}
html = template.render(data)
```

In the template, if i add the following javascript line, the rendering fails (Notice the superscript):

```
var x2 = 'x²';
```

The exception is:

```
File "C:\python_2.7\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 747, in do_mark_safe
File "C:\python_2.7\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py", line 74, in __new__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6689: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can i use an html template containing non-ascii characters with jinja2/python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this i ended up having to using the unicode values for the super script, so for superscript 2, i used u'\xb2'

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    u'x2' : u'x²'
}
```

use unicode string.

Comment: it's not the data that's the problem.  it's the template.  how do i handle this if the template contains non-ascii characters

Comment: @mike01010 what is your `templateLoader` ?

Comment: templatLoader is simply jinja2.FileSystemLoader(...)